# two ssh keys for two different repositories are not working in config

Tags: github, ssh, key, repository

I just added a second ssh key in my .ssh folder on my mac to access the repo of my client.

The second repo I want to access is github.

I prepared my config file like:

Host github.com
IdentyFile ~/.ssh/id_github

Host xyz.*
IdentyFile ~/.ssh/id_xyz

Now I am able to access my clients repository, but not github anymore.

I also tried it with hostName entry but it did not work.

When I try ssh -vvv git@github.com I receive

OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/name/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/name/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/name/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/name/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6

But when I pull, nothing happen.

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards, nullpointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it. After I found out that ssh -vT git@github.com established a connection and ssh git@github.com did not, I removed my vpn from my client and all worked fine. The problem was a running vpn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has a typo.  The configuration option is `IdentityFile`, and it needs to be used in conjunction with `IdentitiesOnly`.

How to configure this correctly can be [seen in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-ssh).

Comment: I dont have the same hosting provider. But I configured it in this way. It is not working. The Typo was only here and not in my file.

I configured it now with Host HostName User IdentitiesOnly, but it is not working. When I want to pull or push from Github, nothing happens and I need to break up with command d

Comment: The same technique will also work for different hosts as well, but you don't need to specify a different `HostName` from the `Host`.  If you're seeing something other than an actual error message about the public key, then please edit your question to show a code block of `ssh -vvv git@github.com` so we can see what's going wrong.  "It did not work" is not very helpful.

Comment: I found out now that I have the same behaviour if I remove all my github stuff from the config. 

Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User xyz
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
        IdentitiesOnly yes

This is in my config file, but it is not working @bk2204